# Infinity scroll on site using ScrollWatch.js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to use ScrollWatch.js to build a web page with infinite scroll but not getting any output. Nothing is being rendered when I run my code, here is a sample of my html

```
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>The Gradient Boost</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'second/css/app/book.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<h2><div data-scroll-watch>First Text</div></h2>
<h2><div data-scroll-watch>Second Text</div></h2>
<h3><div data-scroll-watch>Third Text</div></h3>
<script src="{% static 'second/js/app/book.js' %}"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/scroll-watcher@latest/dist/scroll-watcher.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

book.js

```
(function() {

    var addElements = function() {

        var txt = document.createTextNode('Testing');
        var el;

        el = document.createElement('div');
        el.appendChild(txt);
        document.body.appendChild(el);

        // If we want newly injected elements to be watched, refresh ScrollWatch. It will re-query the dom and start watching new elements.
        swInstance.refresh();

    };

    var swInstance = new ScrollWatch({
        watch: 'div',
        infiniteScroll: true,
        infiniteOffset: 200,
        onInfiniteYInView: addElements
    });

})();
```

and book.css

```
.watch-container {
    font-size: 2em;
    width: 75%;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background-color: #0681CD;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;

}

div {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 200px 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    font-weight: normal
}

div.scroll-watch-in-view {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[This is the documentation I am using as guidance](https://edull24.github.io/ScrollWatch/)

Running this code on codepen seems to give me the error message in my javascript

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ScrollWatch is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your cdn link is not correct, it's `scroll-watcher` not `scrollwatch`, you can try this `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/scrollwatch@2.0.1/dist/ScrollWatch-2.0.1.min.js`
It works on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/07f3b5cb-7b5d-437c-a397-a90beac2c33d/pen/QWbRwoz?editors=1011)

Comment: thanks, seems to be working on CodePen but not on my machine

Comment: yeah, not seeing anything on my browser